# Swift: Extract Section from Wiki article API

Tags: json, swift, wikipedia-api

I want to extract the Event section from a wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/January_4

But I Can't figure out how to do it. I am using SwiftyJSON and Alamofire.

I have managed to use extracts to get the first paragraph of the article with this code:

```
func requestWikiInfo(pickedDate : String){
    let parameters : [String:String] = [

        "format" : "json",
        "action" : "query",
        "prop" : "extracts",
        "exintro" : "",
        "explaintext" : "",
        "titles" : pickedDate,
        "indexpageids" : "",
        "redirects" : "1"

    ]


    Alamofire.request(wikipediaURL, method: .get, parameters: parameters).responseJSON { (response) in
        if response.result.isSuccess{
            print("We got the wikipedia info")
            //print(response)

            let dateJSON : JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)
            print(JSON(response.result.value))
            let pageid = dateJSON["query"]["pageids"][0].stringValue

            let dateDescription = dateJSON["query"]["pages"][pageid]["extract"].stringValue

            self.dayDescriptionText.text = dateDescription
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: I am still stuck with this, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Use this: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=parse&page=January_4&prop=text&section=1

Removing &section=1 will return all the wikitext rather than just the events section (is this always the first section of the pages?). See [the parse docs](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Parsing_wikitext) if you want to tweak it further.